# Co-ordinating worker thread shutdown

Tags: c#, vb.net, multithreading

I've got a `List(Of IWorker)` which contains a number of concretes. `IWorker` in turn has a `Startup()` and `Shutdown()` method.

Inside the Worker class, `Startup()` creates a new worker thread then returns. `Shutdown()` presently sets a private `ShutDownRequested` flag and returns. The flag is checked by the worker thread (at worst every few seconds).

This all works fine but at present the parent app has no way to determine if the Worker has finished shutting down.

I can see a number of ways around this but am not sure what the best one is.

- Add a `State` property to `IWorker`. Should work but I'm going to be polling states which seems a little nasty.
- Make the shutdown command blocking - Would probably be my ideal solution but I'm not sure how to implement it - does the worker `Sunclock` a private object which `Shutdown()` should also try to Synclock after setting the flag?
- Something else?

Any articles, advice or suggestions appreciated. Examples in C# or VB are fine.

Comment: That depends on what you want to do and why. Do you want to block when calling `Shutdown()`? Do you want to show the status to the user? Something else?

Comment: @svick This is running in a console app. Currently, after calling starting the workers, the console just loops every few seconds, reads some status info from the workers and displays it (events handled, bandwidth used, etc...). When the user presses Enter to exit the app, shutdown is sent to each worker. I just want to wait until shutdown has completed, print a confirmaiton of a clean shutdown and then exit. If the app isn't shutting down and a worker exits, it gets recycled and started again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would not try to use locking to block on `Shutdown()`, if you want shutdown to be a blocking operation.

If you can use .NET 4, I would make your internal execute method a Task.  You could then just call `Task.Wait()` to block until it's complete.

If you must use .NET 3.5 or earlier, I would have the `Shutdown()` call, internally, wait on a WaitHandle, such as a `ManualResetEvent`.  The shutdown code could then look like:

```vb
' Include:
Private shutdownEvent as ManualResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false)

Sub Shutdown()
    ShutDownRequested = True
    shutdownEvent.WaitOne()
End Sub
```

The polling loop (thread operation) would then do:

```vb
Sub Execute()
    While Not ShutDownRequested
        ' Do your work
    End While

    ' Before you exit, "set" the event:
    shutdownEvent.Set()
End Sub
```

Comment: And using tasks, you can also easily wait for all of them at once using `Task.WaitAll()`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I'm currently stuck in 3.5 for this project. Can you please explain what benefits your `ManualResetEvent` has over using `Thread.Join` as suggested in another answer?

Comment: @Basiclife The main advantages are:  1) You *can* (optionally) put a timeout on WaitOne(), which would allow you to return and not block forever in the case of a badly written `IWorker`, 2) you don't have to keep a reference to the thread around, which allows it to be GC'ed upon completion.  3) It's very explicit as to what's happening.

Comment: @Reed thanks for the explanation - All very good points, I'll be using this in future.

Answer (score 4):

There is a method [Thread.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.join.aspx) that will block until the thread ends - any use?

Answer (score 0):

Why not add a `ShutdownComplete` event on `IWorker` and make sure its the last thing each concrete does when its complete?  I know it sounds like that might be forcing the implementations to do something specific, but if you have a base class for IWorker, it should be a big deal.  Consider this.

```
public abstract class WorkerBase : IWorker
{
  public event EventHandler ShutdownComplete;
  //...other implemenation details

  public void Shutdown()
  {
    this.ShutdownInternal();
    this.ShutdownComplete(this, EventArgs.Empty);
  }

  protected abstract void ShutdownInternal();

}
```